VBA is "Data Validation"
I Need to verify if a cell in a range has "Data Validation".
I was trying something like this:
Public Sub test()
    
    If isDataValidation(wlTab.Range("A1")) = True Then
        MsgBox "Data Validation is true!"
    Stop
 
End Sub

Is there a similar way?

this may be of use
